# Deauthorize URL not being accessed

Tags: php, facebook

I have a canvas app setup for Facebook and everything so far is working great and as intended with exception to the Deauthorize Callback URL.

The url can be accessed from other people/machines on the Internet. The format of my url is as follows: `http://subdomain.domain.com/phpfile.php`. The php file in question at this point simply generates a debug.txt file just to see if it's being accessed at all. The debug.txt file appears in the directory with every form of access except Facebook's supposed Deauthorize ping.

I have tested it with Facebook's URL tester (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  When using this tool, my debug.txt file is generated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to the servers access logs? Do you see hits from Facebook?

Comment: Yes.  The only hits to my removal php from facebook are the ones that were made via the debug tool.  Does the callback work even if your project is in Sandbox mode?

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not 100% sure.  I would hope so!  I've had some trouble in the past when I didn't specify the callback as an **HTTPS** request... I assume you have an SSL certificate on your server, try setting the callback to an HTTPS url...

Comment: It is not HTTPS.  I have thought about that.  In one of the posts I read, they were saying that it's possible that https was the problem.  In this case there is no SSL setup.  If I need it I do have the ability to, and will.

Comment: If you are able to, I recommend trying to enable SSL on the callback URL.

Comment: ok SSL setup and working.  removing app still does not call the set URL.  this is very frustrating